# How to organise different datasets on Excel into the same layout/order (using pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple Excel spreadsheets containing the same types of data but they are not in the same order. For example, if file 1 has the results of measurements A, B, C and D from River X printed in columns 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively but file 2 has the same measurements taken for a different river, River Y, printed in columns 6, 7, 8, and 9 respectively, is there a way to use pandas to reorganise one dataframe to match the layout of another dataframe (i.e. make it so that Sheet2 has the measurements for River Y printed in columns 1, 2, 3 and 4)? Sometimes the data is presented horizontally, not vertically as described above, too. If I have the same measurements for, say, 400 different rivers on 400 separate sheets, but the presentation/layout of data is erratic with regards to each individual file, it would be useful to be able to put a single order on every spreadsheet without having to manually shift columns on Excel.

Comment: Are the columns named the same across all spreadsheets?

Comment: Yes, but they do not all start on the same row e.g. row 1. Some are on row 5 etc but the headings are always the same.

Comment: If you import all the dataframes and pass a list of column names like cols = [1, 2, 3] and then df[cols], it will organize the columns in that order for all the dataframes.  Then if you use dropna, you can get rid of the null rows.  For the transposed dataframes, you'd need to check if they are transposed (such as having the column names in row values) and then do something like df.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use pandas to reorganise one dataframe to match the layout of another dataframe?

You can get a list of columns from one of your dataframes and then sort that. Next you can use the sorted order to reorder your remaining dataframes. I've created an example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create an example of your problem
root = 'River'
suffix = list('123')
cols_1 = [root + '_' + each_suffix for each_suffix in suffix]
cols_2 = [root + '_' + each_suffix for each_suffix in suffix[::]]
data = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols_1, data=data)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols_2, data=data)

df_1
[out]   River_1  River_2  River_3
0        0        1        2
1        3        4        5
2        6        7        8

df_2
[out]   River_3  River_2  River_1
0        0        1        2
1        3        4        5
2        6        7        8

col_list = df_1.columns.to_list() # Get a list of column names use .sort() to sort in place or

sorted_col_list = sorted(col_list, reverse=False) # Use reverse True to invert the order

def rearrange_df_cols(df, target_order):
    df = df[target_order]
    print(df)
    return df

rearrange_df_cols(df_1, sorted_col_list)
[out]   River_1  River_2  River_3
0        0        1        2
1        3        4        5
2        6        7        8


rearrange_df_cols(df_2, sorted_col_list)
[out]   River_1  River_2  River_3
0        2        1        0
1        5        4        3
2        8        7        6
```

You can write a function based on what's above and apply it to all of your file/sheets provided that all columns names exist (NB the must be written identically).

> Sometimes the data is presented horizontally, not vertically as described above, too.

This would be better as a separate question. In principle you should check the dimension of your data e.g. `df.shape` and based of the shape you can either use `df.transpose()` and then your function to reorder the columns names or directly use your function to reorder the column names.

Comment: Thank you, Jason. When I try to reorder columns in this way I get an array of 'NaN' values. The reordered column headers are displayed across the top in the first row, but also are displayed vertically in the first column to create a NaN matrix.

Comment: @JHayes Can you post the code that you ran? And if possible a small example of what was returned? You can use `df.iloc[:5, :].to_clipboard()` to copy a small example to your clipboard (so that you can paste into your question) and then you can change any private information.

Comment: @JHayes My mistake, I've corrected and updated the my answer. Can you try the above approach and let me know if you have any problems.